# How to add Siri Shortcuts Actions (SiriKit Intents) to an App?

Tags: swift, swiftui, shortcut, sirikit

I'm working on building my first app, and I need to add Siri Shortcuts actions (SiriKit Intents) to it, I honestly am not able to find any reliable resources online which are up-to-date with the latest version of Xcode, I found one by the developer of ToolBox Pro for Shortcuts, but I'm facing a few issues following along in the part two.
Do any of you all know any good resources for learning how to integrate Shortcuts actions into SwiftUI apps? (SwiftUI)

Answer (score 2):

Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app) to add a custom `SiriKit` Intent Definition File to your project. They give you examples of defining intent parameters.

Then use the modifier `onContinueUserActivity` in SwiftUI. More documentation available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/onContinueUserActivity(_:perform:)). That's pretty much all you need to add Siri Shortcuts to your `SwiftUI` project, exactly how I accomplished this in my `SwiftUI` app.

```swift
.onContinueUserActivity(_ activityType: String, perform action: @escaping (NSUserActivity) -> ())
```

Answer (score -1):

To add `Siri shortcut intents` go to `File > New > New File > Sirikit Intent Defination File`

Comment: I know that, but I want to know how to configure Intents

Comment: To configure intents goto siri extension info.plist and define the Intents name in IntentsSupported key. 
Like if your intent name is "siriShortcut" then add the "siriShortcutIntent"  value in IntentsSupported key.